# Having issues visualizing simple arithmetic in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

This will seem quite trivial but for some reason, my tensorboard is coming out completely blank.

Code:

```
sess = tf.Session()

x = tf.constant(1.0, name='input')
w = tf.Variable(0.8, name='weight')
y = tf.mul(w, x, name='output')

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess.run(init)
sess.run(x)
sess.run(w)
sess.run(y)

summary_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter('log_simple_graph', sess.graph)
```

Any feedback would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause is that your program is exiting without [closing](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/train.html#SummaryWriter.close) the `tf.train.SummaryWriter`, and hence flushing the graph to disk. You should be able to fix this by adding the following line at the bottom of your script:

```
summary_writer.close()
```

Comment: Is there any content in your log file?

Comment: The log file is showing an error saying my event is not UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: Can you share the complete error message (including a stack trace)? Thanks!